# Alternative to CDATA for HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, cdata

I want to display strings like `&amp;` in an HTML page, but it is rendered as `&`.
Is there any possibility to tell the browser to display text without processing, something like `CDATA` in XML.

PS. On the server side I am using Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those characters are designed specially to be displayed this way. You can instead send `&amp;amp;` which will display as you wish. Depending on what server side language you use there is likely to be an `HTMLEncode` function which will do this for you.

PS - `PRE` & `CODE` do not work for HTML symbols.

Comment: Actually I am sending `&amp;` But the browser is displaying it as `&`

Comment: Sorry, this site encoded it! Let me spell it out so you can see:
& a m p ; a m p ;
remove the spaces and then you have what I meant you to see :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the need to HTML-encode, but what do you mean by `PRE & CODE do not work for html symbols.`? At least as of this writing, recent browsers do allow, for instance, literal `&` in `<pre>` and `<code>` elements and, strangely, _also_ convert `&amp;` to literal `&`.

Comment: What I mean is what you have discovered, you may expect that PRE/CODE would not convert `&amp;` to `&` but they do.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should do as suggested in Dale Burrell’s answer. It just takes a little extra operations, and possibly care. If you need to display `&amp;`, then you just need to worry about the `&` and enter the rest normally.

But there *is* a secret code, the [`xmp` tag](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2.1). It is well supported in browsers, though it will probably never make its way (back) to specifications. Moreover, in addition to rendering all of the contents literally, it is rendered as a block with vertical margins and in monospace font. This can be handled in CSS, with the usual caveats, e.g.

```
<style>
body, xmp { font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; }
xmp { display: inline; }
</style>
I want to display strings like <xmp>&amp;</xmp> in an HTML.
```

Normally there is little point in using `xmp`, but it can be handy for bulks of data when HTML markup should be displayed as-is. Then you might even want the default rendering, without the stylesheet above.

Comment: Secret sauce! I love it. I wouldn't dream of using it, but i love it.